# Setting rules for outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I have a question regarding multiple rules in outlook. I have a folder inside my inbox named RHS Group. What my intention is, is to have it so that if the word rhsgroup is in the "To" or the "Cc" section I want the email to go to my folder RHS Group. However, if the email is from just one individual person or a selection of emails I want it to go just to my inbox!

Any questions please ask :)

Comment: Oh sorry I missed one thing, I have folders in the "RHS group" folder in which have separate names, for example james and jack, so what i want to happen then is if the name "jack" is combined with "rhsgroup" I want it to go in the folder jack within the "RHS Group", if there isn't a name I want then it will just go into the "Rhs Group" main section. Thanks

Comment: Instead of commenting your own question, you may just edit the question to include any further details.

Comment: Ok thanks, for that ill make sure to do so in the future

Answer (score 0):

See this article:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx

I believe you need the "Move messages sent to a public group to a folder"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but thats not quite what im looking for. I need it so that if its got a specific name "rhsgroup" in the to or cc then it goes to a folder RHS Group, then goes even further into that folder if its from Jack, if its from Jack cc the rhsgroup for example. Whereas if its just from jack it will go to my inbox!